# Looping differences in Ruby using Range vs. Times

Tags: ruby, loops, range

I'm trying to solve a Project Euler problem using Ruby, I used 4 different looping methods, the for-loop, times, range and upto method, however the times method only produces the expected answer, while the for-loop, range and upto method does not. I'm assuming that they are somewhat the same, but I found out it's not. Can someone please explain the differences between these methods?

Here's the looping structure I used

```
# for-loop method
for n in 0..1
  puts n
end

0
1
=> 0..1

# times method
2.times do |n|
  puts n
end

0
1
=> 2

# range method
(0..1).each do |n|
  puts n
end

0
1
=> 0..1

# upto method
0.upto(1) do |n|
  puts n
end

0
1
=> 0
```

Answer (score 11):

This information can be easily obtained by inspecting the documentation.

[`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.src/M002173.html) has a signature of `array.each {|item| block } → array`, so we can see that the return value of `foo.each { ... }` is `foo`.

Likewise, [`Int#upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Integer.src/M001139.html) has a signature of `int.upto(limit) {|i| block } => int`, so that `x.upto(y) { ... }`  will always return `x`.

Then we can also see that `2.times { ... }` will return 2 because of [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Integer.src/M001141.html)'s signature.

I'm having trouble finding the right documentation, but `for x in y...` gets translated to `y.each do |x| ...`, so that's why your for-in loop returns the same thing as your `.each` loop.

Anyway, depending on the *return* values of these looping constructs is... a strange approach.  I don't think this happens much (at all?) in idiomatic Ruby code.

Comment: It doesn't sound to me like he's asking about the return value.

Comment: @sepp2k: I saw that the *output* of each statement was `0 1`, while the return values as indicated by `=>` had 3 different values.  The question could have been worded more clearly, in any case.

Comment: I think the OP is misunderstanding the `=>` being output by IRB, thinking its a normal part of the loop's coded output.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly, you're asking why `n.times` is the only method which iterates upto, but not including `n`. In that case:

For ranges it's simple: `x..y` defines a range from x to y inclusive and `x...y` defines a range from x to y exclusive. So if you want the same behavior as times use `0...n`.

For `x.upto(y)` there is only one version which will iterate upto and including `y`. This is simply how upto is defined and documented to work.

It is also quite clear why `n.times` does not include n: if it iterated from 0 to n (inclusive), it would yield `n+1` times. But since the method is called `n.times` it should clearly only yield n times.